# Ant : how to always execute a task at the end of every run (regardless of target)

Tags: ant

Is there a way to define a task in Ant that always gets executed at the **end** of every run? This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318217/execute-ant-action-always-and-independently-from-target) provides a way to do so, at the **start** of every run, before any other targets have been executed but I am looking at the opposite case.

My use case is to echo a message warning the user if a certain condition was discovered during the run but I want to make sure it's echoed at the very end so it gets noticed.

Comment: Have you tried moving the echo to the end of the build.xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate: ***[How to force a final ant target to execute regardless of dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8403533/1164465)***

Comment: @cpeisert I had a look at the possible duplicate it seemed to be addressing a broader problem.

Comment: @chrislhardin echos outside of any target get executed at the start of the script (even though they may be located at the "end" of the build.xml). This is consistent in the view of the build.xml as a tree-like structure where the textual order doesn't matter. So to execute something before all targets you place it at the "root" of the build.xml, outside of any target. But where to place something that you need to execute *after* all targets?

Comment: You could chain a depends to a final target and up the chain and set the default to that target and place your echoes in that last block. It's a kludge but def would print last.

Comment: Of course you can wrap all your targets into a single target and at the end of that target do your echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting situation. Normally, I would say you can't do this in an automated way. You could wrap Ant in some shell script to do this, but Ant itself really isn't a full fledge programming language.

The only thing I can think of is to add an `<ant>` call at the end of each task to echo out what you want. You could set it up, that if a variable isn't present, the echo won't happen. Of course, this means calling the same target a dozen or so times just to get that final `<echo>`.

I checked through AntXtras and Ant-Contrib for possible methods, but couldn't find any.

Sorry.

Comment: It is a helpful answer in that at least I am not missing anything. I usually use the "call at the end of each task" method since it is easier to examine an ant variable from inside the build.xml script as opposed to from a wrapper shell script.

Answer (score 2):

use a buildlistener, f.e. the exec-listener which provides a taskcontainer for each build result
( BUILD SUCCESSFUL | BUILD FAILED ) where you can put all your needed tasks in, see :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6391165/130683
for details.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your calls in the sequential container.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sequential.html